# Calculating Fourier Series of $ x^2 (t)$

Tags: fourier-series

If Fourier series of $ x(t)=\alpha_k$ then what is the Fourier series of $ x^2(t)$?

I should solve this problem and I do not know where to start.
I know this is not a question and it is vague but Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think that it seems like x(t) is constant, in which case, $x^2(t)$ would also be constant and have fourier series $a_k^2$, although I may very well be wrong.

Comment: @BelowAverageIntelligence thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\left (\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k e^{i k x}\right)^2=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty  c_k e^{i k x}\Rightarrow
c_k=\sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty a_l a_{k-l}.$$